# Simple way to check the internet access when Ping and FTP are not blocked?

Tags: connection

My internet provider disconnects the internet daily and on random. After that I need to authenticate by logging in using browser. I have setup iMacros in Firefox to simulate the authentication, but how do I check when the internet connection is lost? I need a simple solution cause I am no expert.

Ping and FTP seem to work even when the internet access is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You could try by making a script that opens www.google.com  . And put the script to open G each 2-3-10 minutes. If the script opens google with succes do nothing, if doesn't then initiate login procedure. For this purpose you need a JS scripting since you're need if clauses. Maybe you should even consider batch file to check for the connection which would be much easier. But you said FTP and ping works so I am not sure about batch file.

The idea is to make the batch file which would ping a website like google.com and if ping returns error to run macro. All of this is possible if you further explain your problem.

Comment: Thanks, for reply. Ping returns responses even when the internet gets disconnected. I think internet provider blocks ports, probably only port 80, because FTP connects to servers too. 
And how else batch file could check the internet?

Comment: The examples I found just show connectivity test by pinging. I didn't find any other way. Even C# example uses ping to test the connectivity. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/check-internet-connection/

Why don't you just call your provided and explain them your problem?